# Can't Get CoreNLP October 2022 Update to run in R on Mac

Tags: java, r, stanford-nlp

I've been trying to use the most recent update of CoreNLP on my mac and I keep getting the following error message when I run the code below.

```
library(coreNLP)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘coreNLP’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
 call: dyn.load(jli, FALSE)
 error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Internet Plug- 
Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib':
 dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug- 
Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib, 
0x000A): tried: '/Library/Internet Plug- 
Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' 
 (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 
'x86_64', need 'arm64')), 
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Internet Plug- 
Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' 
(no such file), '/Library/Internet Plug- 
Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' 
 (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 
  'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

I seem to be able to install the package no problem, but I can't initiate it. As I understand it, it seems to be some sort of incompatible architecture problem. That is, the error is saying the package is for use on Windows not for Mac. The whole issue seems unusual to me as I used the package before its update last year no problems. Java and R are both up to date on my computer.

Comment: It seems the version of java I had was incorrect, and I needed to download the right version for the M1 chip, which I did using the following resources:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWWMnaFEETc&ab_channel=CodeWithArjun
https://www.oracle.com/nz/java/technologies/downloads/